# Next.js14 shows error while build in Nodejs20. It runs fine in localhost but while build shows error & after deploying shows 500 internal server error

Tags: node.js, next.js, build, gcloud, updates

I have just updated the Node.js version to the latest i.e. version 20, after that I created one next.js latest project. It runs fine in my localhost but while build it shows error and i haven't change any code or anything i just created a new next.js app. How to solve this issue , I want to build this project and want to deploy in gcloud, once I tried to deployed but it shows 500 internal server error. ->

```
C:\Users\Lenovo\OneDrive\Desktop>npx create-next-app@latest radha
√ Would you like to use TypeScript? ... No / Yes
√ Would you like to use ESLint? ... No / Yes
√ Would you like to use Tailwind CSS? ... No / Yes
√ Would you like to use `src/` directory? ... No / Yes
√ Would you like to use App Router? (recommended) ... No / Yes
√ Would you like to customize the default import alias (@/*)? ... No / Yes
√ What import alias would you like configured? ... @/*
Creating a new Next.js app in C:\Users\Lenovo\OneDrive\Desktop\radha.

Using npm.

Initializing project with template: app-tw


Installing dependencies:
- react
- react-dom
- next

Installing devDependencies:
- autoprefixer
- postcss
- tailwindcss
- eslint
- eslint-config-next


added 322 packages, and audited 323 packages in 58s

116 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
Initialized a git repository.

Success! Created radha at C:\Users\Lenovo\OneDrive\Desktop\radha


C:\Users\Lenovo\OneDrive\Desktop>cd radha

C:\Users\Lenovo\OneDrive\Desktop\radha>yarn
yarn install v1.22.19
info No lockfile found.
warning package-lock.json found. Your project contains lock files generated by tools other than Yarn. It is advised not to mix package managers in order to avoid resolution inconsistencies caused by unsynchronized lock files. To clear this warning, remove package-lock.json.
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
warning "eslint-config-next > @typescript-eslint/parser > @typescript-eslint/typescript-estree > ts-api-utils@1.0.3" has unmet peer dependency "typescript@>=4.2.0".
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
success Saved lockfile.
Done in 60.13s.

C:\Users\Lenovo\OneDrive\Desktop\radha>next build
- info Creating an optimized production build
- info Compiled successfully
- info Linting and checking validity of types
unhandledRejection Error: Cannot find module 'next/dist/shared/lib/html-context.js'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\Lenovo\OneDrive\Desktop\radha\.next\server\pages\_document.js
- C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\next\dist\server\require.js
- C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\next\dist\server\load-components.js
- C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\next\dist\build\utils.js
- C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\next\dist\build\worker.js
- C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\jest-worker\processChild.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1048:15)
    at C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\next\dist\server\require-hook.js:110:36
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:901:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1115:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:130:18)
    at 8743 (C:\Users\Lenovo\OneDrive\Desktop\radha\.next\server\pages\_document.js:39:18)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\Users\Lenovo\OneDrive\Desktop\radha\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:25:42)
    at 3262 (C:\Users\Lenovo\OneDrive\Desktop\radha\.next\server\chunks\262.js:45:22)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\Users\Lenovo\OneDrive\Desktop\radha\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:25:42)
    at __webpack_exec__ (C:\Users\Lenovo\OneDrive\Desktop\radha\.next\server\pages\_document.js:63:39) {
  type: 'Error',
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\radha\\.next\\server\\pages\\_document.js',
    'C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\next\\dist\\server\\require.js',
    'C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\next\\dist\\server\\load-components.js',
    'C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\next\\dist\\build\\utils.js',
    'C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\next\\dist\\build\\worker.js',
    'C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\next\\dist\\compiled\\jest-worker\\processChild.js'
  ]
}
- info Collecting page data .`
```

Answer (score 0):

update your .eslintrc.json file like this.

```
{
  "extends": ["next/babel", "next/core-web-vitals"]
}
```